# JSF Out Of Memory

Tags: jsf, primefaces, out-of-memory

I'm creating an application with PrimeFaces 5.3, JSF 2.2, Omnifaces 2.3.
I'm using the jdk v8, Glassfish 4.1.1 and MySQL 5.

I'm using the application OWASP ZAP in order to give more information from the security point of view.

The problem is that I'm experiencing some "out of memory - JavaHeapSpace"

```
  Avvertenza:   #{detailsController.loadDetail}: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  javax.faces.FacesException: #{detailsController.loadDetail}: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:562)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.classicvirus.jsf.LoggedUserWebFilter.doFilter(LoggedUserWebFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 46 more
  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractBytes(DataHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$1.doExtract(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2762)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3991)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
```

and if I wait some minutes I see this logs

```
  WARN:   WELD-000714: HttpContextLifecycle guard leak detected. The Servlet container is not fully compliant. The value was 1
  WARN:   WELD-000225: Bean store leak was detected during org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl association: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3a7067d8
  WARN:   WELD-000225: Bean store leak was detected during org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl association: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3a7067d8
  WARN:   WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active, most likely it was not cleaned up properly during previous request processing: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3a7067d8
  Grave:   Unable to load class: 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

  Avvertenza:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My supposition is related to the images management. I'm using images retrieved from the database, with the approach I've saw in the past
facelets implementation

```
  <p:graphicImage value="#{applicationScopedBean.imagesFromDb}">
      <f:param name="imageId" value="#{actualAd.favouriteImageId}" />
      <f:param name="cvlTimeStamp" value="#{now}" />
  </p:graphicImage>
```

application scoped bean

```
public StreamedContent getImagesFromDb() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {
        String imageId = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("imageId");
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(advertisingImageManager.getById(Long.valueOf(imageId)).getContent()));
    }
}
```

I've switched to the omnifaces approach but no luck

Facelets

```
 <o:graphicImage value="#{applicationScopedBean.getImageById(actualAd.favouriteImageId)}" class="img" lastModified="#{now}"/>
```

applicationScopedBean

```
public byte[] getImageById(Long imageId){
    return advertisingImageManager.getById(imageId).getContent();
}
```

The question is not "in which way I can solve this problem".
But, first of all. It's correct to investigate about this problem created by the OWASP ZAP application?
If yes, from where can I start my investigations?

Comment: Run a profiler. That's the only way to investigate memory consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the bult-in profiler inside Netbeans.

I've saw that the problem was in a field of type byte[] that was representing an image.
In my case the size of this field was 1.8Mb, and with a lot of sessions this situation was creating an out of memory error.

The error is solved wrapping the byte[] in a new entity and using the FetchMode.LAZY

Comment: Good job. I'd only like to note that this was also hinted in documentation of <o:graphicImage>.

Comment: Yes, you're right and all my doubts was started because I've read the omnifaces documentation. So congratulations for the clear documentation. It's more useful than people think in my opinion, and before to "try" I always read all the documentation because in this way you can create your own knowledge. Thank you!